# Angular 9 ngx-image-cropper resize cropper with slider

Tags: angular, cropper

I'm using an `ngx-image-cropper` library in my project. I would like to crop image only in aspect ratio 16/9, and that's okay. I have set `aspectRatio` to 16/9 and cropper is rectangle. I have also implemented `mat-slider`, which should change only width and height of image cropper just like it works with dragging arrows of the cropper to scale it. Is it possible, to add to mat-slider event of resizing cropper exactly how it works with changing cropper scale by dragging arrows? I don't want to scale image with mat-slider, but only cropper. I have searched in `ngx-image-cropper` library but I have not found anything which will be appropriate for my needs. Thanks for any help!

Link to the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper

```
    <div class="image-cropper-dimensions">
      <image-crop
        [imageFile]="data.file"
        [cropWidth]="sliderValue"
        [aspectRatio]="16 / 9"
        [isFileStrip]="true"
        [roundCropper]="data.isRoundedCropper"
        (onImageCropped)="onImageCropped($event)"
      >
      </image-crop>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-edit-container">
    <mat-slider
      [min]="SLIDER_MIN_VALUE"
      [color]="'primary'"
      [value]="sliderValue"
      [step]="SLIDER_STEP"
      (input)="onSliderChange($event)"
    >
    </mat-slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my application I change only with and height with this command:
[maintainAspectRatio]="false"

This is  a little part from my code:

```html
<image-cropper
  [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
  [imageURL]="imageUrl"
  [transform]="transform"
  [maintainAspectRatio]="false"
  [aspectRatio]="aspectRatio"
  [canvasRotation]="canvasRotation"
  (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
></image-cropper>
```

Comment: Yes, and in my application I need to make this resize exactly how it works with maintainAspectRatio, but with a slider